# Does submitting in PhilArchive affect submission in journals?

Tags: reference-request, introduction-to-philosophy, methodology, publications

I wanted to submit a paper to PhilArchive (an open-access e-print archive in philosophy). If I want to submit this paper to a journal afterwards, does this prior submission to PhilArchive affect the journal's decision?

Comment: You can also try the Academia stack. I recall a post where Elsevier software flagged/detected the author’s same paper pre-released on Arxiv.  Whether that lessened the chance of acceptance I’m not sure.

Comment: @JKusin Thanks for your answer. I post a similar question on the Academia stack. However, since this problem is field-dependent, I propose the question here first.

Comment: The answer depends on the terms and conditions of the specific journal to which you subsequently submit the paper.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common to upload a paper to PhilPapers or other preprint servers before it is accepted. If the journal is triple-blind or blind reviewed, it can become harder for the editor to find referees who do not know your identity. But as the review process in philosophy can be extremely long, my view is that this disadvantage is usually outweighed by the advantage of making your paper available.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I found it very useful. Can I ask you to recommend some preprint servers in philosophy other than Philpapers?

Comment: I also post my papers at academia.edu. Some people don’t like it because it is for profit, but people in humanities or social sciences won’t find your work if you only post it on philpapers. There is also philsci-archive if your work is on philosophy of science or maths